# DataView - Reverse RowFilter condition

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with a customizable filter implemented with RowFilter. For each column, the user can specify a filter criterium. Once all the desired criteria have been set, he clicks on "Apply filter". The criteria for all columns are combined to create the RowFilter expression of the DataView.

Now, I want to implement a "Reverse" option (a check box) which would simply reverse the RowFilter condition of the DataView. My first thought was to simply say:

```
RowFilter = NOT (original condition)
```

And that would be it. Apparently not, because of fields with NULL values. For example, if the filter has the condition `StatusID = 10`, and if some records have the NULL value for StatusID, the condition `NOT (StatusID = 10)` will not include those records (according to my tests). For one field, I could easily make the change to account for NULL but, when several fields are combined in the condition, it becomes more complicated.

My question: is there a clever way to globally reverse the RowFilter condition when fields with NULL values are involved, or do I have to test for NULL for each individual field?

Comment: Can you not do myDataView.RowFilter = "[NAME OF Column1]<>0"

Comment: Replacing "=" by "<>" leads to the same problem as using NOT. Instead of "StatusID = 10", I have to say "StatusID <> 10 OR StatusID IS NULL". That is what I would like to avoid (with little hope, I must admit).

Comment: Please check the answer whether this suits your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood your question you want to get the rest of the result set which is not filtered.
I know there is no direct NOT function as you have shown in your pseudo code.
What you can do is get the dataview based on filter first which probably you have already in place like something below:

```
DataView dv= //Whatever filter you use
```

Then convert it to a datatable by using `DataView.ToTable()`

Next you can easily find the difference between these two datatable(s) like

```
var rowsOnlyInDt1 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(r => !dt2.AsEnumerable()
                .Any(r2 => r["col1"].Trim().ToLower() == r2["col1"].Trim().ToLower() && r["col2"].Trim().ToLower() == r2["col2"].Trim().ToLower()));

DataTable result = rowsOnlyInDt1.CopyToDataTable();
```

which is another table and gives you reverse results.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In the end, I may use it (getting the difference between the unfiltered data and the filtered one). I did not think about that way of doing it.

Comment: There is no such NOT you are thinking.You must tackle it logically.One way I have shown which I have used and works.

Comment: The NOT exists but does not give the "remainder" of the straight condition. I guess that is your meaning.